# How can I pull a Twitter post as soon as it is posted using Tweepy so I can then have it posted on Reddit using RPAW?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, reddit, praw

So far I have something that will pull the most recent Twitter post from a specified account and then post it with my Reddit account to a specified subreddit. However, I want a code that will take any new post from a specified Twitter account and post them automatically to my Reddit account on a specified subreddit. Here is my code so far. I am not sure what I can do to know when someone has posted on Twitter to then pull the most recent post. Is there another way?

```
import time 
import tweepy
import praw

# Variables that contains the credentials to access Twitter API and REDDIT
USERNAME = ''
PASSWORD = ''
CLIENT_ID = ''
CLIENT_SECRET = ''
API_KEY = ''
API_SECRET = ''
ACCESS_TOKEN = ''
ACCESS_SECRET = ''


# Setup access to API 
def connect_to_twitter_OAuth():
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(API_KEY, API_SECRET)
    auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET)

    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    return api


# Create API object
api = connect_to_twitter_OAuth()

tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = '', count = 1, include_rts =False, tweet_mode = 'extended')

for info in tweets[:1]:
    print('ID: {}'.format(info.id))
    print(info.created_at)
    print(info.full_text)

#For the reddit post
TITLE = info.full_text
ID = format(info.id)

URL = "https://twitter.com/twitter/statuses/" + str(ID)

SUBREDDITS = ['']


class Reddit:
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.reddit = praw.Reddit(
            client_id=config["CLIENT_ID"],
            client_secret=config["CLIENT_SECRET"],
            username=config["USERNAME"],
            password=config["PASSWORD"],
            user_agent="Script by u/wtfox",
        )

    def post(self, subreddit, title, url=None):
        if url:
            submission = self.reddit.subreddit(subreddit).submit(title=title, url=url)
        else:
            submission = self.reddit.subreddit(subreddit).submit(
                title=title, selftext=text
            )
        return submission


def main():
    assert TITLE is not None
    assert URL is not None

    config = {
        "CLIENT_ID": CLIENT_ID,
        "CLIENT_SECRET": CLIENT_SECRET,
        "USERNAME": USERNAME,
        "PASSWORD": PASSWORD,
    }

    reddit = Reddit(config)
    for subreddit in SUBREDDITS:
        print(f"Posting to {subreddit}:\n{TITLE}\n{URL}\n\n")
        sub = reddit.post(subreddit, title=TITLE, url=URL)
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want Tweets in realtime, you should use [streaming](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.6.0/streaming.html).

Comment: Thank you I am looking into what I can do with streaming now!